# Error while moving directory if already exist in java

Tags: java, java.nio.file

I am trying to move directory forcefully that means if already exist then overwrite without asking.

**Code :**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.System;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

public class MoveDirectory {


    private static void movefilesandfolder(String sourceFilevar,String  destinationFilevar)
    {

                System.out.println("source="+sourceFilevar);
                System.out.println("destination="+destinationFilevar);

                Path sourceFile=Paths.get(sourceFilevar);
                Path destinationFile=Paths.get(destinationFilevar);

                try {

                        Files.move(sourceFile, destinationFile,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
    }

    /**
     * Sole entry point to the class and application.
     * @param args Array of String arguments.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       movefilesandfolder("C:\\FTPDownload\\Downloaded\\epi141225_0001","C:\\FTPDownload\\In_Progress\\epi141225_0001");
    }
}
```

Error output:

```
source=C:\FTPDownload\Downloaded\epi141225_0001
destination=C:\FTPDownload\In_Progress\epi141225_0001
java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: C:\FTPDownload\In_Progress\epi141225_0001
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(WindowsFileCopy.java:372)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:286)
    at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1345)
    at MoveDirectory.movefilesandfolder(MoveDirectory.java:22)
    at MoveDirectory.main(MoveDirectory.java:36)
```

This code works if Folder not present on destination path but fails if already exist. This code doesn't work even if empty folder is present on destination path.

```
Files.move(sourceFile, destinationFile,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

In this call option i am using is not working for folder. This code Tested for file and it worked for already exist file as well.

But I want to move/overwrite folder.

Comment: What would you expect to happen if the destination folder exists and is not empty? Should the contained files be deleted?

Comment: As i mentioned in first line move directory forcefully that means if already exist then overwrite without asking

Comment: If an empty destination directory exist: don't create a new one with the same name. If an destination directory exist containing files: you have to take care of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete destination directory before moving, or, if you want to merge directories together, loop your directory files and move anyone in new folder

```
System.out.println("source="+sourceFilevar);
                System.out.println("destination="+destinationFilevar);

                Path sourceFile=Paths.get(sourceFilevar);
                Path destinationFile=Paths.get(destinationFilevar);

                try {
                        if(new File(destinationFile).exists()){
                              // DELETE DIRECTORY
                        }
                        Files.move(sourceFile, destinationFile,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

or

```
    System.out.println("source="+sourceFilevar);
                    System.out.println("destination="+destinationFilevar);

                    Path sourceFile=Paths.get(sourceFilevar);
                    Path destinationFile=Paths.get(destinationFilevar);

                    try {
                            if(new File(destinationFile).exists()){
                                  // for each file in sourceFile
                                  //     Files.move file ...
                            }else{
                            Files.move(sourceFile, destinationFile,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                           }

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

Comment: It means there is no use of "StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING"   in case if we want to move folder {Its useless /skip by API}

Comment: The option is used for `Replace an existing file if it exists.` see the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardCopyOption.html#REPLACE_EXISTING). It's not mentioned for directories, where it makes no sense to me. You can see it also on the comments about how to handle the containing files.

Answer (score 0):

javadoc:

```
public static Path move(Path source,
                        Path target,
                        CopyOption... options)
             throws IOException
```

Move or rename a file to a target file.

By default, this method attempts to move the file to the target file, failing if the target file exists except if the source and target are the same file, in which case this method has no effect. If the file is a symbolic link then the symbolic link itself, not the target of the link, is moved. **This method may be invoked to move an empty directory.**

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `Path.resolve(other Path)` method like this

```
Files.move(sourceFile, destinationFile.resolve(Paths.get(sourceFile).getFileName()), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)
```

Java docs, give the best explanation about [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...)).